# how to prevent bootstrap navbar split into few lines when collapsed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, bootstrap-5

I've been searching for it all day and couldn't find a solution, so I hope I won't look like an idiot when in 2 minutes someone will post an answered link for the exact question.

I am trying to create a navbar like on [steamdb](https://steamdb.info/)
Where the search box remains after the navbar collapse and is just reduced in size.

But I ran into the problem where if I set the navbar to `<nav class="navbar-expand-lg" </nav>` then when it collapses it split into 3 lines, one for the brand, one for search, and one for toggle dropdown.

If I remove the "-lg" then it doesn't split, but then it also doesn't change the items to toggle.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">My Company Name</a>
      <form class="d-flex w-100 d-inline-block">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control no-border" type="text" placeholder="search for game..." id="example-search-input">
            <span class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn rounded-pill" type="button">
              <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
              </button>
            </span>
        </div>
      </form>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-expanded="false">
              content
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/test1">test1</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/test2">test2</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/test3">test3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Donate</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/uaWJpGVRED

Please help, I've been stuck on this all day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 2 inner divs inside the container. Make them both `w-100`, and the first one `d-flex` so that the brand and form layout horizontally...

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="d-flex w-100">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">My Company Name</a>
              <form class="d-flex w-100 d-inline-block">
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <input class="form-control no-border" type="text" placeholder="search for game..." id="example-search-input">
                      <span class="input-group-append">
                          <button class="btn rounded-pill" type="button">
                              <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
                          </button>
                      </span>
                  </div>
              </form>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> content </a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/test1">test1</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/test2">something</a></li>
                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/test3">bla bla</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Donate</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
  </nav>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/KED3siE8bJ)

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me see if I get this clearly, as this sent me back to the docs to look at what d-flex and w-* does. By changing this. And how d-* works in general in bootstrap. So what I did there was changing the collapsed toolbar to be flex, which means row by default. So then in that view it can't go to 2 lines. And by setting the search box as w-100 I force it to take all the space it can. The second one changed to w-100 is just to prevent it from getting into the first one. I got it right?

Comment: Actually you don't need to the `w-100`. Please accept the answer so others know the question is solved.

Comment: Yea, i realized later that the w-100 cause problem. Anyway, thanks